# I need to set alert for SL and TP of the following Pinescript code indicator

Tags: pine-script, alert, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I need to set alert for SL and TP of the following Pinescript code indicator.thanks in advance.It already has alert for Buy and Sell. I just need alert for SL and TP no matter if it is for Buy or Sell. i tried to put alert for SL and TP but it was not working properly. this pinescript code is version 5. Buy and Sell alerts work properly. I dont need seperate alerts for Long SL and TP and Short SL and TP. just want an alert for SL no matter if it is short or long and an alert for SL or TP if it is Long.

```
var float SCR = 0.
var ATR = 0.
var TradeOn = false
Shape = false 


color GREEN           = color.rgb(4, 191, 101)
color TAIL            = color.rgb(20, 141, 154)
color RED             = color.rgb(246, 7, 7)
color _Green          = color.rgb(2, 106, 89)
color OFF             = color.new(color.red,100)
string DYNAMICSLG     =  "➞ Risk To Reward Settings " 
string CORE           =  "➞ Core Settings "
var array<int> score  = array.new_int(2,0)



var bool ShortTrade   = false
var bool TradeisON    = false
var bool LongTrade    = false
var line res          = na
var line sup          = na
var line tpLine       = na
var line SLLine       = na
var label LAB         = na
var float TP          = 0.0
var float SL          = 0.0
var float Res         = 0.

bool BUY              = false
bool SELL             = false
bool Filter           = input.bool(false,"ATR Body Filter",group = CORE)
float Target          = input.float(1.3,"Target",step = 0.1 , tooltip = "Target And stop         Multiplyer",group = CORE)
bool SLType           = input.string('Close',
     'SL Type', ['Close', 'High/Low'],
     group=CORE,tooltip = "Activate SL on candle close or high/low") == 'Close'

float Risk            = input.float(100,"Risk Per Trade (USD)",group=CORE)    

bool ShowSL = input.bool(false,"Show SL",group = CORE)
string Linestyle      = input.string('Dashed',
     'Line Style', ['Solid', 'Dashed', 'Dotted'], group=CORE,inline= "Line")

color Bull = input.color(GREEN,"",group=CORE,inline= "Line")
color Bear = input.color(RED,"",group=CORE,inline= "Line")    


method volAdj(int len)=>
    math.min(ta.atr(len) * 0.3, close * (0.3/100)) [20] /2

PF = volAdj(30)


BodyRange() =>
    math.abs(close - open) 

BodyCon = bar_index > 100
BodyCon1 = (Filter ? BodyRange() < ta.atr(5) * 1 : true)


if timeframe.change("1D") and not TradeisON 

    ATR := volAdj(30)
    SCR:=hl2 - (ATR* 15)
    TradeOn:= true
    Res:= SCR + (ATR* 25)
    res:=line.new(bar_index, Res,bar_index, Res,color = #5c439a,style = line.style_solid)
    sup:=line.new(bar_index, SCR,bar_index, SCR,color = #5c439a,style = line.style_solid)



if TradeOn
    res.set_x2(bar_index)
    sup.set_x2(bar_index)

if ta.crossover(close[1],Res) and BodyCon and BodyCon1
    BUY:=true
if ta.crossunder(close[1],SCR) and BodyCon and BodyCon1
    SELL:=true
            
linefill.new(res,sup,color = color.new(color.from_gradient(close,ta.lowest(5),ta.highest(10),   #3a6186,#89253e),80))



//----- { SL Calculation

x2 = low - ta.rma(ta.tr(true), 14) * 1.5
xz = ta.rma(ta.tr(true), 14) * 1.5 + high
longDiffSL2 = math.abs(close - Res)
longDiffSL = math.abs(close - SCR)
// }

Long = BUY and not TradeisON     
Short = SELL and not TradeisON
TradeFire = Long or Short

if Long and not TradeisON
    LongTrade:= true
    ShortTrade:= false

if Short and not TradeisON
    LongTrade:= false
    ShortTrade:= true


if true 
    if TradeFire and not TradeisON
        TP := switch
            Long  => close + (Target * longDiffSL)
            Short => close - (Target * longDiffSL2)

        SL := switch
            Long  => close  - longDiffSL
            Short => close  + longDiffSL2

        TradeisON:= true
        if true
            line.new(bar_index,
                 Long ? high : low,
                 bar_index,
                 TP,
                 width=2,
                 color = TAIL,
                 style= line.style_dashed)

            tpLine:= line.new(bar_index,
                 TP,
                 bar_index+2,
                 TP,
                 style= line.style_dashed,
                 color = TAIL
                 )
            if ShowSL     
                SLLine:= line.new(bar_index,
                     SL,
                     bar_index+2,
                     SL,
                     style= line.style_dashed,
                     color = RED
                     )     
            LAB:=label.new(bar_index,
                 TP,
                 "Target",
                 color = TAIL,
                 style= label.style_label_left,
                 size=size.small,
                 textcolor = color.white
                 )
    if TradeisON
        line.set_x2(tpLine,bar_index)
        label.set_x(LAB,bar_index+1)
        if ShowSL
            line.set_x2(SLLine,bar_index)
      

    if LongTrade and TradeisON
        if high >= TP
            label.set_color(LAB,GREEN)
            score.set(0,score.get(0)+1)
            TradeisON:=false
        if  (SLType ? close : low)  <= SL
            score.set(1,score.get(1)+1)
            label.set_color(LAB,color.new(RED,70))
            label.set_tooltip(LAB,"Stoploss Hit : "+ str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(SL)))
            TradeisON:=false

    else if ShortTrade and TradeisON
        if low <= TP 
            label.set_color(LAB,GREEN)
            score.set(0,score.get(0)+1)
            TradeisON:=false
        
        if (SLType ? close : high) >= SL 
            score.set(1,score.get(1)+1)
            label.set_color(LAB,color.new(RED,70))
            label.set_tooltip(LAB,"Stoploss Hit : "+ str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(SL)))
            TradeisON:=false

BearCon = TradeisON and ShortTrade
BullCon = TradeisON and LongTrade

barcolor(BearCon ? RED : BullCon ? _Green : color.rgb(52, 52, 54) )

plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color = BearCon ? RED : BullCon ? _Green : color.rgb(52, 52,   54),
     wickcolor = color.rgb(103, 99, 99),bordercolor = BearCon ? RED : BullCon ? _Green :   color.rgb(52, 52, 54))

bgcolor(BearCon ? color.rgb(136, 4, 15, 90) : BullCon ? color.rgb(8, 191, 158,90) : na )

// where is my table ?!
var tb = table.new(position.top_right, 6, 6,
  bgcolor= color.new(color.gray,80))
if barstate.islast
    GrossP = score.get(0) * (Risk * Target)
    GrossL =  score.get(1) * Risk
    PNL = GrossP - GrossL
    table.cell(tb, 0, 0, "Winning Trades"
      , text_color = #a3a3b1)
    table.cell(tb, 1, 0, str.tostring(score.get(0))
      , text_color = #08c09b)

    table.cell(tb, 0, 1, "Losing Trades"
      , text_color = #a3a3b1)
    table.cell(tb, 1, 1, str.tostring(score.get(1))
      , text_color = #cd0202)


    table.cell(tb, 0, 2, "Gross Profit"
      , text_color = #a3a3b1)
     table.cell(tb, 1, 2, str.tostring(GrossP)
      , text_color = GrossP > 0 ? #1eddd4:#cd0202 )

    table.cell(tb, 0, 3, "Gross Loss"
      , text_color = #a3a3b1)
    table.cell(tb, 1, 3, str.tostring(-GrossL)
      , text_color = #cd0202 )

    table.cell(tb, 0, 4, "Final PNL"
      , text_color = #a3a3b1)
    table.cell(tb, 1, 4, str.tostring(PNL)
      , text_color = #ba7726 )
```

alertcondition(Long,"BUY")
alertcondition(Short,"Sell")

I tried many ways to put alert for SL and TP but not successful.